# HTTP POST multipart form-data

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, xamarin

I'm working on an App in Xamarin.Forms. I want to send the Post Request to an API with form-data. In the code below, it returns the success message, but the data isn't posted there.

```
public class Post {
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string HolderFirstName { get; set; }
    }

public async void SendProof(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
    Uri URL = new Uri(string.Format("http://11.222.333.44:4000/api/v1/Proof/SendProofNameRequest"));
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    var post = new Post {ConnectionId = "9c12dba2-6cb9-4382-8c96-f1708a7e8816", HolderFirstName = "Carl Dreyer"};
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post);
    var response = await _client.PostAsync(URL, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data"));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) { 
    await DialogService.AlertAsync("Credential Proof Sent Successfully!");}
    }

    catch(Exception error) {
    await DialogService.AlertAsync(error.Message); }
    }
```

Binding for Button which triggers this Function.

```
public ICommand SendProofCommand => new Command(() => SendProof(default, default));
```

Comment: Have you tested your service with Postman or some other tool to verify that it works correctly?  Have you checked the logs or debugged it?  If you are getting a 200 but the data is not saving it stands to reason that the error is in the service code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task SendProof()
        {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://11.222.333.44:4000/");
                var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

                var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

                nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ConnectionId", "9c12dba2-6cb9-4382-8c96-f1708a7e8816"));
                nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("HolderFirstName", "Bergman"));
                var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://11.222.333.44:4000/" + "api/v1/Proof/SendProofNameRequest") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };

                var res = await client.SendAsync(req);

                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DialogService.AlertAsync("Proof Sent Successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    await DialogService.AlertAsync("Unsuccessfull!");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception error) {
            await DialogService.AlertAsync(error.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is this?  did you solve your own problem?  If so, you should add some explanation of what the problem is so others can learn from it

Comment: It's better not to istantiate new `HttpClient` per request but reuse a single instance for all further requests. Also `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` are `IDisposable`, consider to respect that.